# Finding Application's Installation Directory on Windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, installation-path

I have a java Application for which I have made an installer. In code, I need to know about where user have installed the application, as it is up to the user to install the application in his favorite directory. So how do I get this information using java code? I need it specific to windows platform.

Comment: (At least) two possibilities.  Write the location (from your installer) to a known location (probably within `user.home`) or use `new File(".")` or `user.dir` to get a reference to the current directory

Comment: This gives me user's home directory, C:\users\abc. I want to get application directory, like C:\Program Files\MyApplication. where MyApplication is up to user's choice, he may use a different drive as well.

Comment: Write the install location to a install.property file during install the program and when you want to get it just read the file.

Comment: @saffer `System.getProperty("user.dir")` will give you the current working directory of the application, but I wouldn't rely on it.  Writing a value from your installer into a file inside the `user.home` location gives you central point from which you can then look up that value later, from anywhere.  The question is, why do you need it?

Comment: @madProgrammer Application puts some resources to its installation directory, that I need to use those while the application is running. That's why I need it. ok for instance a user opens a file from let say D: root directory using that Application, user.dir will give me D:\ right? but the resources that I need are not placed at D:\, they are in the directory where application is installed, for instance C:\Program files\App\resources. how do I get this directory to read resources that are placed there?

Comment: @Safeer Without testing it, I don't know what the execution context might be.  This is why, as I keep saying, you need to write a configuration file to `user.home` during the installation phase, which contains the location the program was stored.  Then it doesn't matter when you want to read it or where you were started, you can find it in the `user.home` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to find out where application is installed, as it is left up to user. So one way to get the application's installation directory is using environment variables on windows machine. When you make the installer, set an environment variable (you can create new one say "XYZ" variable or also can use to an existing one), and set its value to application directory(as you didn't mention the installer you are using so I am not able to tell how would you do this in building the installer for your application). Once you have done this, you can get value of this environment variable in java code, which will give you the installation directory of your Application. here is code for getting value of env var XYZ:

```
System.getenv("XYZ");
```

Comment: How do I create this env var at time of installation? and how would I give it the installation path?

Comment: That depends on your installer you are using. Look for options to create env vars during installation. and set it's value to app directory or path that the Installer must be providing you

Comment: ok I got an option to create environment variables in installer. but that did not create any variable, I have checked. any idea?

Comment: where did you check it from? you can use set command on windows cmd to see all the environment variables

Comment: yes it is shown in the list of variables. ok so next step?

Comment: Is it setting the right value for this variable? If yes, simply run your application and enjoy. make sure to add changes in your application code to get value of this environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` which will give you the programs current working directory, but this might not be the installation directory.

Instead, from your installer, write a file to the `System.getProperty("user.home")` location (call it something like `.MyApplicationConfig` to make it a hidden file, or put it within a directory in `{user.home}\AppData\Local`) which contains the installation location chosen by the user.

This will allow you to read the file at some time in the future, from any where as it's stored in a central, known location

Comment: {user.home}\AppData\Local
Would that be safe enough to save path to resources that my app use?
I mean what if this gets deleted somehow ? you know users ;)

Comment: In that case I won't be able to access path to resources. right?

Comment: Then what happens if the user decides to move the program after it's installed?

Comment: :)
Then its a madUser ;)
for AppData/Local I was asking it because many times we use it for storing temporary data as well. so users are not supposed to mess with installed programs but not similar in case of other temp storage :)
Anyways let me try this option of storing installation path to a config file.

Comment: We store configuration data here as well as it's the only writable location we can find ;)

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for your help, for now I can use this option, until I find some other more secure option. actually I wanted a solution which can give me the path of where the application is executing from. In that case even if user moves application after installing, it will still work as I get the path to where ever he puts the application folder. :)

Comment: It's even worse on MacOS, as the execution context is shifted to the `user.home` :P